# how to calculate 10% above and 10 % below a number?

Tags: percentages

**let say i have a number 10 how can i find number which is 10 % above and 10 % below this number.how do i calculate  i am reading about %.please tell how to find it**

> how to calculate 10 % increase and % below of the number.**lets say the Number is 10**
>   i am new to percentage thing need help.please tell me the formula how to do it !!

Comment: Just being discreet: If you're a fifth grader, moderators will probably have to remove your account because it's against StackExchange's terms of service to have a person younger than 13 on their site.

Comment: Further info on the age issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102250/231933

Comment: tl;dr if you're concerned about the age of a user you can use the SE [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to get in touch with staff, though you are under no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 3):

When you say “$10\%$ above $n$,” it is the number  $n+ \frac{10}{100}\times n=1.1\times n$ (note that $\frac{10}{100}\times n$ is $10\%$ of $n$). Similarly, $10\%$ below  $n$ is  $n-\frac{10}{100}\times n=0.9\times n$.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a $10$% increase, multiply by $1.1$ ($110$%).
To calculate a $10$% decrease, multiply by $.9$ ($90$%).

The makes sense. If you want to add $10$% you multiply by $1+\frac{1}{10}$.  If you want to subtract $10$% you multiply by $1-\frac{1}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate $10$% of $10$. This is $0.10(10) = 1$. So, $10$% of $10$ is $1$.

Now, $10%$ above $10$ is just $10 + 1 = 11$. And $10$% below $10$ is just $10 - 1 = 9$.